# How prove $ y^2=x^3+x+1370^{1370}$ has at least 6 answers in $ \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

How prove that $  y^2=x^3+x+1370^{1370}$ has at least 6 answers in $ \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: There was a problem in an Iran math contest, the question was with $y^3=x^3+x+1370^{1370}$, is it this one?

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I would start:
First we set $L := 1370^{685}$ for readability.
Two trivial solutions for $y^2=x^3+x+L^2$ are $P_{1,2}=(0,\pm L)$.

Using the double formula for elliptic curves given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_doubling) we get two new points on the curve:

$\lambda = \frac{1}{2L} ; x_3=\frac{1}{4L^2} ; y_3=-(L+\frac{1}{8L^3})$

Plugging it in it can be veryfied that $P_{3,4}=(x_3,\pm y_4)$ are indeed on the curve.
My guess would be that another doubling or maybe an addition will lead to another two solutions. I don't have the time right now to do it. I might come back later and test it.

Edit:
5th and 6th solution by adding $P_1$ and $P_3$:

$P_{5,6}=(\pm 8L^2(8L^4+1) , 512L^9+96L^5+3L)$

@Nate: Good point.

Comment: You have two pairs of inverses with respect to the group law, if you add two of them from different pairs you must get something new. So you can probably deduce the existence of two more points without any more calculations.